# IST time is not accurate php

Tags: php

In php I have set the follwing

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

but it is not displaying accurate time.

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

this is the link of my website http://www.adsnjobs.com/

here I have echo the time zone and current date time by using

```
echo date_default_timezone_get() . date('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
```

Comment: Is there any daylight saving on the location?

Comment: What exactly does "not displaying accurate" mean? What version of PHP are you using? Do you have DST over there?

Comment: it is not accurate because now in india time is 2:18pm and its saying 10:19pm and the date is same

Comment: When I look at your page, I can see this : Asia/Kolkata2013-09-12 02:19:58 pm which seems to be accurate ?

Comment: but on my side it is not accurate it is saying 10:49pm what is wrong??

Comment: @MandeepSingh: It's not possible that the code you give above would display different results to different users. Are you sure this is the code? And you are getting the results from the same web server as we do?

Comment: You forgot to update the page, press F5, empty cache? The PHP output depends on the servers clock, not on the client one.

Comment: I'm getting the same result as OP. I think something is amiss

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the newer DateTime class, just as good practice:

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a');
```

Second, have you tested whether the issue is with your server clock, not the IST time zone? It looks about 10 minutes off to me. Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a :: T');

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Etc/UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a :: T');
```

This will show you the date in UTC and in IST so you can see if there is a 5:30 offset. If there is, it's your server clock.